# How can you remove the schedule or deadline property from an entry in the agenda view in orgmode

Tags: emacs, org-mode

From the agenda view, I want to press a key and remove the SCHEDULED: <... > line from that TODO entry.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Press `C-u C-c C-s` to remove a `SCHEDULED` property.

Press `C-u C-c C-d` to remove a `DEADLINE`.

To rebuild the agenda buffer, press `r`

See the agenda commands in [The manual](http://orgmode.org/org.html#Agenda-commands)

Comment: Of course, I realize this is more than 'a key', but that's what orgmode offers, and it's a whole lot easier than changing buffers to make the change.